# E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb on **ubuntu 14.04** and I am following the steps on [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

But when I get to the step:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get the following error :

```
root@sabbir-pc:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

And I get to the step:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.1 mongodb-org-server=3.0.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.1
```

I found the following problem

```
root@sabbir-pc:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.1 mongodb-org-server=3.0.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-server
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-shell
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-mongos
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-tools
```

How can I solve this problem?
I also follow [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org) link (same problem), but no result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the PPA

```sh
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I already do this as I mention on the link doc.mongodb.org

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I wrong to write the list file for mongo where we insert the mongodb repository within Ubuntu sources list.

I strongly suggest to rewrite the following commands (for 14.04):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that you will be able to install the latest mongodb version:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

All described in the MongoDB website:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=1.85252765.529335644.1441475542#install-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I Mongodb doesn't support 32 bit operating systems. I faced the same problem as above until I realised that my os is 32 bit. Please verify if your os is 32 bit

[mongodb installation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install version 3.0 of MongoDB. I think there is some compatibility that needs to be resolved before we on Ubuntu 14.04 can actually install without errors.

What I did was just follow the installation for Mongodb-org version 2.6.9. That is the closest to version 3.0. The installation guide is very detailed and you will have no problem following it.

After installation, simply do a

> sudo apt-get update

This will update any outdated package(s).

and to make it easy, here is the link to the installation guide for version 2.6.9

> http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

hope that helps... let me know if it works for you or anyone has found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will resolve all your issues

Try this:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

sudo apt update


apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev

sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev


sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.17 mongodb-org-server=3.4.17 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.17 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.17 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.17
```